# How to read a large file using multi-processing?

Tags: python, python-3.x, parallel-processing, multiprocessing

I am trying to process a 51GB text file in Python. Here is my attempt at processing this file in parallel:

```
def parallel_read(pid, filename, num_processes):
    with codecs.open(filename) as infile:
        for num, line in enumerate(infile):
            index = num % num_processes
            if index != pid:   # Only process lines corresponding to your ProcessId. Discard others.
                continue
            process_line(line)   


def main(file_to_read):
    num_processes = 8
    arguments = []
    for x in range(num_processes):
        arguments.append((x, file_to_read, num_processes))
    pool = mp.Pool(num_processes)
    results = pool.starmap(parallel_read, arguments)
```

Questions:

1. Is this really going to speed things up? I mean the file is still being read sequentially by each of the processes, just that the processing is restricted only to specific lines. IMO this might speed things up assuming processing of a line takes significantly more time than reading a line.
2. Are there any limits on the number of processes I can start in Parallel, especially wrt how many file connections I can open in Parallel? (In other words, if I have access to an 80 core machine, can I run 160 processes in Parallel?)
3. Is there a better way to read large files in Parallel in Python?

Comment: Is what you're doing I/O- or cpu-bound? Multiprocessing is better fro the latter because it will allow the computations to run concurrently and not interfere with one another. There are many caveats, though. For example if the results of the computations all have to be collected together back in the main process (which involves a lot of additional I/O overhead).

Comment: From my own experience I can only advise you to do this implementation in C or C++ and output the preprocessed data in an easy to read format unless this is a one time task. Python is horrendously slow and has very bad multithreading support IMO. Working with these kind of files will show these weaknesses. Also be extra careful with big memory structures when using multiprocessing as they 1) need to be replicated by each process and 2) need to be transferred when forking

Comment: As an example: I had a dataset about 8gb which contained some information i needed for the processing. Just using multiprocessing without any due care will result in the whole dataset being replicated and  transferred into each forked process on first access. This transfer time was measureable in minutes and I quickly ran out of memory.

Comment: Nothing it passing the `pid` to your `parallel_read()` function, btw.

Comment: @martineau: "Nothing it passing the pid to your parallel_read() function, btw." -- Sorry I didn't get this comment. The `process_line` is cpu-bound.

Comment: @SebastianHoffmann: I totally understand your pain as a past sufferer myself. That is why, I am only passing the filename in the parallen_read function which is then reading the file one at a time.

Comment: I meant that the `pool.starmap()` which is what calls your `parallel_read()` function provides no `pid` argument, nor does anything else — so the processing related to it can't be done within the function.

Comment: _Is this really going to speed things up?_ benchmarking > speculation. What are you trying to speed up, anyway? Most of the post focuses entirely on the IO, but isn't the actual processing usually the issue?

Comment: @martineau Unless I'm missing something, isn't the `pid` argument created in `for x in range(num_processes):` loop?

Comment: @AMC: Oops, missed that — my mistake.